# MySQL join has drastically worse performance after upgrading from 5.6 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, mysql-5.7, aws

I have a fairly straightforward query that has become very slow after upgrading from MySQL 5.6.35 to MySQL 5.7.12 (running on AWS RDS).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Name,d.id,deviceType,issuedBy, description,avNum,CompanyName,
  BrandName,dwNumber,quant,discDate,Type
FROM table_one d     
JOIN table_two i ON d.id = i.id;
```

In 5.6, this query completes in 90 seconds.  After upgrading to 5.7, it’s taking over 30 minutes.  Each table has approximately 2 million rows.

I started by comparing the optimizer settings between 5.6 and 5.7:

```
# 5.6
index_merge=on
index_merge_union=on
index_merge_sort_union=on
index_merge_intersection=on
engine_condition_pushdown=on
index_condition_pushdown=on
mrr=on
mrr_cost_based=on
block_nested_loop=on
batched_key_access=off
materialization=on
semijoin=on
loosescan=on
firstmatch=on
subquery_materialization_cost_based=on
use_index_extensions=on
```

```
# 5.7
Optimizer settings in 5.7:
index_merge=on
index_merge_union=on
index_merge_sort_union=on
index_merge_intersection=on
engine_condition_pushdown=on
index_condition_pushdown=on
mrr=on
mrr_cost_based=on
block_nested_loop=on
batched_key_access=off
materialization=on
semijoin=on
loosescan=on
firstmatch=on
subquery_materialization_cost_based=on
use_index_extensions=on
condition_fanout_filter=on
derived_merge=on
duplicateweedout=on
```

The only changes I see were the last three options in 5.7.  I switched them off as follows:

```sql
SET optimizer_switch='condition_fanout_filter=off';
SET optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
SET optimizer_switch='duplicateweedout=off';
```

This had no effect.  Next, I looked at the differences in my innodb settings (my 5.7 instance has more memory, hence the pool size differences).

```
# my innodb changes 5.6 -> 5.7
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts added in 5.7, set to ‘8’
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size set to 8388608 in 5.6, removed in 5.7
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown changed from ‘OFF’ to ‘ON’
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct added in 5.7, set to ’25’
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup changed from ‘OFF’ to ‘ON’
innodb_buffer_pool_size changed from 2,804,940,800 to 11,811,160,064
innodb_checksum_algorithm changed from ‘innodb’ to ‘crc32’
innodb_deadlock_detect added in 5.7, set to ‘ON’
innodb_default_row_format added in 5.7, set to ‘dynamic’
innodb_file_format changed from ‘Antelope’ to ‘Barracuda’
innodb_file_format_max changed from ‘Antelope’ to ‘Barracuda’
innodb_fill_factor added in 5.7 set to ‘100’
innodb_flush_sync added in 5.7 set to ‘ON’
innodb_log_checksums added in 5.7 set to ‘ON’
innodb_log_write_ahead_size added in 5.7 set to 8192
innodb_max_undo_log_size added in 5.7 set to 1,073,741,824
innodb_mirrored_log_groups removed in 5.7, set to ‘1’ in 5.6
innodb_numa_interleave added in 5.7 set to ‘OFF’
innodb_page_cleaners added in 5.7 set to ‘4’
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency added in 5.7 set to ‘128’
innodb_strict_mode changed from ‘OFF’ to ‘ON’
innodb_temp_data_file_path added in 5.7, set to 'ibtmp1:12M:autoextend'
innodb_undo_log_truncate added in 5.7, set to ‘OFF’
```

I reviewed the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html)
and attempted to switch off the following:

```
innodb_strict_mode=‘OFF’
innodb_deadlock_detect=‘OFF’
innodb_flush_sync=‘OFF’
innodb_log_checksums=‘OFF’
```

Also, no effect.

I’m hoping someone might be able to tell me what is going on here?  The query is part of a larger workflow, which has become unusable as a result.  I'd like to get the 5.6 behavior back if possible, but with my limited DBA knowledge, I'm running out of things to try.  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction or give me additional avenues to investigate.

Below are my tables.  Many of the columns have large widths, and they are mostly defined as `VARCHAR(X) DEFAULT NULL` because the data source isn't clean (I don't have control over the source).  Note that I need utf8 data, but I am using latin1 while I troubleshoot the slow query, to eliminate that as a possible cause of the slowness.  (The reason we need to migrate from 5.6 -> 5.7 is for the larger index sizes in 5.7, which can accommodate our larger UTF8 column sizes).

(Also, I should point out that the `id` field is coming from the source data, and is a long string of alphanumeric characters of variable width (up to ~30 characters), so I need it to be a VARCHAR).

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table_one` (
  `id` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `RecordKey` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VersionStat` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VersionNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VersionDate` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PublishDate` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DistStart` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DistCommStat` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BrandName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VersionModelNumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Catalog` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dwNumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceCount` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Exemption` varchar(1100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PreMarket` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DevDRMT` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DTKit` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Combination` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Usage` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SingleBatch` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SerialNumber` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ManuDate` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpDate` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Donation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LabeldWithMLO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NLabledMLO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MLOStatus` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BTT` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BRC` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PriorUse` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table_two` (
  `id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deviceType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issuedBy` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avNum` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quant` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PkgStatus` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_table_two_id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

EXPLAIN is identical between the two as well:

```
explain extended SELECT DISTINCT ...

******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: d
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: 
      key_len: 
          ref: 
         rows: 1596593
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using temporary
******************** 2. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: i
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_table_two_id
          key: idx_table_two_id
      key_len: 203
          ref: mydb.d.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra:
```

**UPDATE #1:**

Here is some more information.  I enabled the performance schema on both servers.  The 5.7 server shows many `hash_table_locks`:

```sql
SELECT EVENT_NAME, COUNT_STAR
       FROM performance_schema.events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name
       ORDER BY COUNT_STAR DESC LIMIT 10;


# EVENT_NAME, COUNT_STAR
'wait/synch/sxlock/innodb/hash_table_locks',   '3256808433'
'wait/synch/mutex/innodb/buf_pool_mutex',      '19266748'
'wait/synch/mutex/innodb/log_sys_mutex',       '14488781'
'wait/io/table/sql/handler',                   '13676918'
'wait/synch/mutex/innodb/lock_mutex',          '11431841'
...
```

Additionally, I see a lot of time being spent in `wait/io/table/sql/handler`, presumably because of the `hash_table_locks`.  They are the top two consumers of time (in picoseconds):

```sql
SELECT EVENT_NAME, SUM_TIMER_WAIT
       FROM performance_schema.events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name where event_name != "idle"
       ORDER BY SUM_TIMER_WAIT DESC LIMIT 10;

# EVENT_NAME, SUM_TIMER_WAIT
'wait/io/table/sql/handler',                 '1300909619487480' # 1300s
'wait/synch/sxlock/innodb/hash_table_locks', '98099101074540'   # 98s
'wait/io/file/innodb/innodb_data_file',      '5035505718525'
'wait/io/socket/sql/client_connection',      '344937541275'
'wait/synch/mutex/innodb/fil_system_mutex',  '198749837865'
...
```

When I repeat this on the 5.6 server, I don't see the `hash_table_locks` consuming time like this.

**UPDATE #2:**

To check if the disk is the bottleneck, I did the following.

I installed two identical EC2 instances.  They are both i3.large (2 vCPU / 15.25 GB RAM) along with 1x425 GB SSD disk.  On the first instance, I installed MySQL 5.7.25.  On the second instance, I installed MariaDB 10.2.21.  I kept the out of the box configuration for both.  The query on MySQL still takes 30 minutes, but the MariaDB instance only takes 30 seconds!  The versions of InnoDB are nearly identical: MySQL is running 5.7.25, and MariaDB is running 5.7.24.  It seems to me this must be a configuration issue within MySQL, rather than a limitation of Innodb or the disk.

Another update:  within the MariaDB instance, the EXPLAIN is slightly different.  There is a "using where" clause, and the tables are reversed.  I attempted a STRAIGHT_JOIN to change the table order, but that didn't change anything:

```sql
# MariaDB
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT
  Name,d.id,deviceType,issuedBy, description,avNum,CompanyName,
  BrandName,dwNumber,quant,discDate,Type
FROM table_one d    
JOIN table_two i ON d.id = i.id;


******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: i
         type: ALL
possible_keys: idx_table_two_id
          key:
      key_len:
          ref:
         rows: 2496908
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
******************** 2. row *********************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: d
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 202
          ref: mydb.i.id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
2 rows in set
```

I've also applied Wilson's suggested changes below, which have not resolved the issue.

**UPDATE #3:**

I've found something that looks significant.  I enabled the query tracer on my 5.6 and 5.7 servers.  I've attached their output here:

5.6: https://pastebin.com/KSTeTDdy

5.7: https://pastebin.com/3SaXNdCU

At the very end, I noticed the temporary tables are created differently:

```
# 5.6
{
  "converting_tmp_table_to_myisam": {
    "cause": "memory_table_size_exceeded",
    "tmp_table_info": {
      "table": "intermediate_tmp_table",
      "row_length": 4570,
      "key_length": 4585,
      "unique_constraint": true,
      "location": "disk (MyISAM)",
      "record_format": "packed"
    }
  }
}
```

```
# 5.7
{
  "converting_tmp_table_to_ondisk": {
    "cause": "memory_table_size_exceeded",
    "tmp_table_info": {
      "table": "intermediate_tmp_table",
      "row_length": 4575,
      "key_length": 8,
      "unique_constraint": true,
      "location": "disk (InnoDB)",
      "record_format": "packed"
    }
  }
}
```

5.6 is using MyISAM for the tmp table, and 5.7 is using InnoDB.  <s>Maybe this is why I'm seeing so many occurrences of `wait/synch/sxlock/innodb/hash_table_locks` in 5.7?  Could this have to do with InnoDB row level locking?  The question is, is it possible to restore the old behavior to test?</s>

I found `internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine` and changed it to `MyISAM` on the 5.7 server.  That does not resolve the issue either.  I can see the temp table being created under /tmp:

```
# ls -ltrh /tmp
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  56K Apr 26 02:27 #sql_f55_0.MAI
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 368M Apr 26 02:27 #sql_f55_0.MAD
```

It's definitely using MyISAM now, but the query is still slow.  I do notice that on all servers, 5.7, 5.6, and MariaDB, this file size goes to 368M and then stops getting larger.  The file grows MUCH faster in 5.6/MariaDB (~10-15 MB/s) compared to 5.7 (<1MB/s).

Comment: Why is the `DISTINCT` needed and why doesn't the 2nd table have a PRIMARY KEY or any UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: Additional information request from your 5.7.nn instance. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  This is staging data that we are loading from externally provided source files.  The "id" in both tables represents the same "product" id in both tables, but it is not unique in the second table.  Distinct is needed because we have identified those columns as corresponding to "distinct" products in our catalog, but in the source data, there are multiple rows for those columns.

Comment: @WilsonHauck This is on RDS, so I can't run commands on the host or access my.cnf.  I can pastebin the values of my parameter group though.  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST: https://pastebin.com/3zf6aw4g, SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/2xdxNR5J

Comment: @WilsonHauck The host has been up for less than 24 hours, so I'll send SHOW GLOBAL STATUS tomorrow.

Comment: Lastly - 

The 5.6 host is 1 CPU / 3.75 GB.  The 5.7 host is 4 CPU / 16 GB, so it's actually larger.

Comment: Thanks for info you have made available.  Will look for tomorrow SGS results.  Posting of your parameter group would allow cross check to SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES that are running values.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Ok, I have the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS, after 24 hours: https://pastebin.com/1rpk0cZt   - Also I updated the post with some information from the performance schema tables.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Thank you, will begin analysis today.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Just FYI, I added a second update.  I installed my server into EC2 to test, so I have more control over the host (the issue is repeateable there as well).  I can run some of the additional commands you requested tomorrow.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Thanks for your additional info.  Please post results of A) SELECT 
 COUNT(DISTINCT id),
 COUNT(*)
FROM table_one; - and - 
B) SELECT 
 COUNT(DISTINCT id),
 COUNT(*)
FROM table_two;     With this GOOFY editor manager the second count should be COUNT opening parenthesis, asterisk, closing parenthesis, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Results from table_one: 1936295, 1936295. Results from table_two: 1936295, 2457645

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Conclusion, you have a ONE to MANY relationship from table_one to table_two on your ID VARCHAR values to be matched in your query.  Could you change your configurations to consistently use LOG_OUTPUT=TABLE,FILE and consistently have SLOW_QUERY_LOG=ON?  If you could then you could share a SLOW QUERY LOG at the end of your working day from any version implemented.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Here is the slow query from the 5.7 instance (the new EC2): https://pastebin.com/eKVV7NkA    - also see my latest update (#3) above.  I think I found something using the query tracer.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for the two tables on each version (if possible).  And `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES  WHERE name LIKE '%table%';` so we can see row_format and file_format (etc).  And `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: I can sympathize with your "garbage in" problem.  However, shouldn't you load the data into some staging table, fix what you can, then move it to the 'real' table(s).  This also gives you a chance to 'normalize' any columns that have repetitious strings.  This will provide some performance improvement.

Comment: If there are dup rows in the second table, wouldn't it be better to de-dup as you ingest them?

Comment: Does MariaDB also show the performance difference or is it always slower or always faster for this query?

Comment: @RickJames See the following: https://pastebin.com/BJmNqB75 - We're actually using these as staging tables to process data prior to loading into our production tables.  It's part of an ETL (or "ELT", more accurately I suppose) process we run.  The "id" field is acting as a foreign key into the first table, and the rows in table two are additional information related to rows in table_one.  I'm sanitizing the names in order to share the tables - calling them both "id" may have been misleading.

Comment: @eckes I tried MariaDB 10.2/10.3 and did not experience the drastic slowdown there.  I only tested to try to eliminate InnoDB as the potential bottleneck.  Everything we currently run is in MySQL.

Comment: Alas, no useful surprises in the pastebins.

Answer (score 2):

Analysis of VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS:
(Alas, nothing here jumps out as an explanation of the Question in hand)

I dislike doing `FORCE INDEX`, etc, but `STRAIGHT_JOIN` may be the simplest and safest way to force the ordering of the two tables.

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.25-log
- 15.25 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 14:05:48; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

With SSD, change these:

innodb_flush_neighbors = 0  -- from 1
   innodb_io_capacity = 800    -- from 200

It sounds like your dataset size is considerably less than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  So, perhaps you are paying for more RAM than you need?  If you are preparing for growth, then ignore this comment.

With rare exceptions, I don't think `innodb_deadlock_detect` should be OFF.

A lot of poorly performang queries.  Crank down long_query_time and make use of the slowlog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Since only 11 connections seem to be needed, lower `max_connections` to, say 40.  This will avoid certain pressures on RAM.

Are you sure you want `READ-UNCOMMITTED`?

**Details and other observations:**

`( Table_open_cache_misses / (Table_open_cache_hits + Table_open_cache_misses) ) = 272 / (6879 + 272) = 3.8%` -- Effectiveness of table_open_cache.
-- Increase table_open_cache and check table_open_cache_instances.

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 4 = 4,096` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners

`( innodb_page_cleaners / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 4 / 8 = 0.5` -- innodb_page_cleaners
-- Recommend setting innodb_page_cleaners to innodb_buffer_pool_instances

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 494,639 / 720896 = 68.6%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size is bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 3,590,832,128 / 11264M = 30.4%` -- Percent of buffer pool taken up by data
-- A small percent *may* indicate that the buffer_pool is unnecessarily big.

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 50,748 / 60 * 128M / 2513408 = 45,166` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size. (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( innodb_thread_concurrency ) = 0` -- 0 = Let InnoDB decide the best for concurrency_tickets.
-- Set to 0 or 64. This may cut back on CPU.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( innodb_deadlock_detect ) = innodb_deadlock_detect = OFF` -- 5.7.15 provides way to speed up heavy inserting by turning off deadlock detection
-- Do you really want to turn it OFF?

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Questions ) = 37,591 / 73621 = 51.1%` -- Pct of queries that needed on-disk tmp table.
-- Better indexes / No blobs / etc.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 37,591 / 46560 = 80.7%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size; improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (168 + 0 + 2 + 0) / 170 = 1` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_scan ) = 51,492 / 50748 = 1 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 51,492 / 71543 = 72.0%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( ( Com_stmt_prepare - Com_stmt_close ) / ( Com_stmt_prepare + Com_stmt_close ) ) = ( 2 - 0 ) / ( 2 + 0 ) = 100.0%` -- Are you `( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED. ROW is preferred; it may become the default.

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Threads_created / Connections ) = 11 / 197 = 5.6%` -- Rapidity of process creation
-- Increase thread_cache_size (non-Windows)

`( thread_cache_size / max_connections ) = 21 / 1320 = 1.6%`
-- (0 for Windows)

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 21 / 11 = 190.9%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

You have the Query Cache half-off. You should set both query_cache_type = OFF and query_cache_size = 0 . There is (according to a rumor) a 'bug' in the QC code that leaves some code on unless you turn off both of those settings.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Com_set_option = 6.7 /HR
Handler_read_rnd = 0.85 /HR
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written / Innodb_dblwr_writes = 1.05
Select_range = 0
Select_range / Com_select = 0
Sort_rows = 0.85 /HR
Table_locks_immediate = 0.03 /sec
Table_open_cache_hits = 0.14 /sec
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
(Com_select + Qcache_hits) / (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) = 420
Com_alter_user = 0.071 /HR
Com_flush = 12 /HR
Com_purge = 12 /HR
Com_release_savepoint = 0.071 /HR
Com_savepoint = 0.071 /HR
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 145
Handler_read_rnd_next / Handler_read_rnd = 2.43e+6
Handler_savepoint = 0.071 /HR
Handler_savepoint_rollback = 0.28 /HR
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 1.24
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost = 2
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:&
gtid_mode = OFF_PERMISSIVE
have_ssl = YES
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_flush_sync = OFF
innodb_log_checksums = OFF
log_output = TABLE
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog = OFF
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
relay_log_recovery = ON
session_track_system_variables = time_zone, autocommit, character_set_client, character_set_results, character_set_connection
time_zone = UTC
transaction_isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED
tx_isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I need to spend some time to go through this.  I started on RDS, and now I'm on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance while I troubleshoot.  I set READ-UNCOMMITTED in an attempt to see if things "sped up" based on lots of "hash_table_locks" that I was seeing in the performance tables.  After further reading, this doesn't seem to impact my SELECT statement.  These are staging tables, so I'm mostly interested in speed.  We regularly clear and reload them with the latest data.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile - By "latest data" do you mean that you replace the entire contents of 'real' tables?  Or do you just augment the tables?

Comment: We augment the 'real' tables.  The staging tables (the ones I'm working with here) get truncated and then reloaded.  @RickJames

Answer (score 1):

You have increased RAM with increase innodb buffer pool size from ~2G to ~11G which is ~70% of total RAM seems okay to me.

Since the execution plan and DB configurations are look same, You may look into your hardware configuration.  Confirm two things from hardware side:

1. Comparison of CPU clock speed between previous and the current one
2. Previous and current Disk category (writing/reading capability) of the machine and if there are any disk striping you are using.

For safer side, would you anlayze the table.  If table size is smaller, you can also optimize this to remove any fragmentation.  To get fragmentation report, you can run [mysqltuner](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl) tool on your database.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Sanjeeva

Comment: It's in AWS RDS and I don't have that level of access to the hardware so I can't run mysqltuner per my understanding of it.  The 5.6 instance is a db.m3.medium (1 CPU/ 3.75 GB of ram).  The 5.7 instance is a newer model, db.m4.xlarge (4 cpu / 16 GB), so it's on a newer/faster server.  Both use SSD.  I've tried on servers of different sizes with similar results.  I can consistently reproduce it by spinning up a new 5.6 instance, or a new 5.7 instance.  It seems to be a 5.6 -> 5.7 issue.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Is your RDS Dedicated or Shared on a server?  Database Storage Option you are using?  A) General Purpose (SSD) or B) Provisioned nnn IOPS (SSD) or C) Magnetic (rotating)?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I'm using the standard (non-dedicated) instances for both.  General purpose SSD for both.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile  Thanks, my suggestions after you post SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; will be influenced by this additional information.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Unfortunately I'm doing this on a test RDS instance, and it was shut down last night.  I restarted it a few hours ago, but it means I have about another 18 hours to go again.  In the meantime, here's SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after I ran the query.  https://pastebin.com/RW1QViQQ  - I'll post it again in the morning after 24 hours has passed.

Comment: Your performance, I believe, is neither restricted by CPU nor by RAM as you have both ample in your instances. I also believe that it is not a version issue.  The probable reasons of your slow performing DB between 5.6 and 5.7 is because of the SSD. Use this "http://rdsinstances.info/?selected=db.m3.medium,db.m4.xlarge" to see the Diff between your machine(disks). For m3 you have **SSD stripped into 4** and hence getting more IOPs and hence getting performance.  Would you check what SSD you are selecting for your m4 machine? AWS has types of SSDs itself with/without striping for various IOPs

Comment: @thisissanjeeva.com I'm using general purpose SSD (gp2) on the m4 machine.  I'm attempting to provision a 100GB db.m3.medium to test against with 3,000 provisioned IOPS, but it's taking a long time to complete.  In the meantime, I installed two identical i3.large EC2 instances (2 vCPU/15.25 GB/ 1x425 GB SSD).  I installed the MySQL 5.7.25 on one and MariaDB 10.2.21 on the other.  I used the out of the box configuration settings.  The behavior is the repeated in this case as well.  MySQL takes 30 minutes to complete, MariaDB takes only 30 seconds.  It doesn't look like the SSD.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Can you POST from 5.6 SHOW CREATE TABLE table_one; and SHOW CREATE TABLE table_two; please.  Thanks

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Your UPDATE #2 needs to be consistent in MARIADB version # involved.  Only you can edit for consistency/accuracy.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile From your new server, Please post from MySQL 5.7.25 SHOW INDEX FROM table_one and table_two. EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ..... Please post from MariaDB SHOW INDEX FROM table_one and table_two. EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE .....  for comparative analysis of INDEXes and Query Plan of optimizer conclusions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck CREATE TABLE statements https://pastebin.com/LR0sVx20

Comment: @WilsonHauck From new 5.7.25 server: SHOW INDEX: https://pastebin.com/spUenm3w and EXPLAIN: https://pastebin.com/S4QELM3c

Comment: @WilsonHauck and from the MariaDB server: https://pastebin.com/Ma8tLQrm

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing your tables, they both use unique identifiers for the field ID, so the distinct clause is not necessary (and it's expensive), so you are free to remove it.

Change the order of your tables in your query, by swapping **table_one** and **table_two** as follows:

```
SELECT Name,d.id,deviceType,issuedBy, description,avNum,CompanyName,   
BrandName,dwNumber,quant,discDate,Type
FROM table_two d 
JOIN table_one i 
ON d.id = i.id;
```

Once you do that, when you run the explain query you should see in the **extra section** the following: **Using where**, and no longer the **Using temporary** (after removing the distinct).

In my MySQL 5.6.43 box, I get this result.

```
    explain SELECT d.Name,d.id,d.deviceType,d.issuedBy, i.description,d.avNum,i.CompanyName,    
i.BrandName,i.dwNumber,d.quant,d.discDate,d.Type
 FROM table_one i inner  JOIN table_two d 
ON d.id = i.id;
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+----------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref      | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+----------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | ALL  | PRIMARY          | NULL             | NULL    | NULL     |    1 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ref  | idx_table_two_id | idx_table_two_id | 203     | upc.i.id |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+----------+------+-------+



explain SELECT d.Name,d.id,d.deviceType,d.issuedBy, i.description,d.avNum,i.CompanyName,    i.BrandName,i.dwNumber,d.quant,d.discDate,d.Type 
FROM table_two d inner  JOIN table_one i 
ON d.id = i.id;

+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+----------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ALL    | idx_table_two_id | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | eq_ref | PRIMARY          | PRIMARY | 202     | upc.d.id |    1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+---------+---------+----------+------+-------------+
```

Please run the explain commands as I've put them, and tell me if you get the same result as I.

Also try running your query without the distinct and see if you get a significant performance gain.

Comment: I did try to swap them.  Unfortunately it did not have an impact.  The 5.6 and 5.7 EXPLAINS are identical, it's the MariaDB EXPLAIN that is different.  So I'm not entirely sure if that's causing the issue.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please try the recommendations there, and tell me your results.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran - Without a `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, the Optimizer ignores the order of `JOINs`.  So swapping will not matter.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran The id field in table_two is not unique, so I do need the distinct.

Answer (score 1):

On Apr 21, 2019 ypercube pointed out the absence of a PRIMARY KEY and no UNIQUE specification for your table_two. Consider the following, please.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_two` (
`aincid` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`id` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'idUNKNOWN',
`Name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`deviceType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`issuedBy` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`avNum` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`quant` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`discDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`PkgStatus` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `idx_table_two_id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Then post EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...... results, please.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Please post current TEXT results from 5.6 and 5.7 of SHOW INDEX FROM table_one; and SHOW INDEX FROM table_two;  as well as results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_one; and SHOW CREATE TABLE table_two;

Comment: @blindsnowmobile A) Have you tried this suggested version of SHOW CREATE TABLE on 5.7?  B) How long does it take to complete?  C) How long does it take the query to complete on MariaDB?   MariaDB has much different optimizer than 5.6 or 5.7.

Comment: Yes, I'm working through a few things that still aren't making sense to me right now.  I'll post an update shortly.

Comment: Here is the information you requested: https://pastebin.com/rJ1qNcxk

Comment: I've come across something rather strange.  When I change the character encoding of one of the tables to `utf8mb4`, my EXPLAIN changes, and I get a "Using index condition" and `ref=func`....  and the query completes in ~1 minute!  If I turn both tables into `utf8mb4` tables, or both `latin1` tables, I lose the index in the `Extra` column and it becomes slow again.  Here is a paste where I changed table_two to `utf8mb4`: https://pastebin.com/MsmCxFEJ  - it is otherwise identical to the latin1 version.  Doesn't make sense... Why would it choose an index based on the charset of the table?

Comment: this may be similar to this blog post - https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2012/08/20/why-wont-mysql-use-the-best-index-in-a-join/, can you run EXPLAIN EXTENDED once again and SHOW WARNINGS after?

Comment: @jerichorivera Looks related.  Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/szVu1WY5 and I see `convert(`mydb`.`d`.`id` using utf8mb4)`.  In my case though, it actually runs MUCH faster with the convert.  That seems pretty strange.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile - The _table's_ charset is irrelevent; the _column's_ is important.  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` after changing in order to verify that the _column_ changed.

Comment: `key_len: 802  ref: func` and `(convert(`mydb`.`d`.`id` using utf8mb4)` imply converting the `id` from latin1 to utf8m4.  This will slow down the `JOIN` _some_, but does not explain the strangeness.

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Please view my profile, Network profile for contact information.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS  Suggestions for your 5.7 instance [mysqld] section to consider,

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles for the function
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to allow higher IOPS on your SSD
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 26
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 47,391
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from 512K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 574
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of web site mentioned in my profile, Network profile and additional suggestions and free Utility Scripts are available.

Comment: Unfortunately the query is still slow after applying these settings.  I notice that MariaDB reverses the join order of the tables and has a "using where" clause in the EXPLAIN.  Looking into that now.

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL have diverged significantly with respect to subquery and join optimization.

Comment: @RickJames Gotcha, thanks.  I was trying to separate out the InnoDB storage engine as being the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find out on what state query is stuck using processlist or using profiler ?

Try :

```
mysql> SET SESSION profiling = 1; 
mysql> <<EXECUTE YOUR QUERY >>;
mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR << Query Id >>;
```

If your query is staying in `statistics` state, then you need to look for `optimizer-search-depth=#` parameter.

Hope this may help.